# How to show textview selection handle in android with java code

Tags: android, textview, copy, selection, actionmode

text is selected but no selection handle.and I don't want to use textIsSelectable="true" in xml.
my code like this:
Editable edit = tv.getText();
Selection.selectAll(edit);

but no selection handles.
how to fix it?

Comment: please explain a more you question

Comment: Do you mean you want to show the custom cut paste options as we see in normal androids text view?

Comment: ((EditText)v).selectAll(); try this